# JavaScript bottom-up tree transformer aimed for performance

Tags: javascript, algorithm, tree

```
function transform(tree,fn){
    var root = tree,
        node = tree,
        child,
        parent,
        is_node,
        dir;
    root.dir = 0;
    while(true) {
        is_node = typeof(node)==="object";
        dir = is_node ? node.dir : 2;
        if (dir < 2)
            child = node[dir],
            node.dir++,
            child.parent = parent = node,
            child.dir = 0,
            node = child;
        else if ((changed = fn(node))!==undefined)
            changed.parent = parent,
            changed.dir = 0,
            node = changed;
        else
            if (!parent)
                return node;
            else
                parent[parent.dir-1] = node,
                node = parent,
                parent = node.parent;
    };
};

// TEST
var tree = [[1,2],[[3,4],[5,6]]];
console.log(
    JSON.stringify(transform(tree,function(a){
        if (a[0]===1) return [3,[5,5]];
        if (a[0]===5) return 77;
    })) === "[[3,77],[[3,4],77]]");
```

I need to make this function as fast as possible, no matter what. I'm aware this is far from the optimal implementation. How could I improve it? Asm.js, maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm,

I don't think your code works,

```
var tree = [[1,2,[1,2,[5]]],[[3,4],[5,6]],[1,2,[1,2,[5]]],[[3,4],[5,6]]];
```

gives

```
[[3, 77], [[3, 4], 77], [1, 2, [1, 2, [5]]], [[3, 4], [5, 6]]]
```

I would have expected that you want that last [5,6] to be 77 in your fiddle.

Furthermore, as RoToRa mentioned

- It is not clear in your code what you want to achieve
- Comma separated statements to avoid curly braces are evil, python much?
- Going through a tree pretty much asks for a recursive solution because you need to keep track of where you are

This function seems to do what you want thru recursion:

```
function transform( node, f )
{
  node = f(node) || node;  
  var index = node.length;
  if( index )
  {
    while( index-- )
    {
      node[index] = transform( node[index] , f );
    }
  }  
  return node;
}
```

Or, if you drop those curlies which you seem to like:

```
function transform( node, f )
{
  node = f(node) || node;  
  var index = node.length;
  if( index )
    while( index-- )
      node[index] = transform( node[index] , f );
  return node;
}
```

I originally wanted to use `[].map` which would be cleaner, however you insisted speed.

Update: I checked jsperf for the fastest loop and it turns out there is a new loop variant that blows the other approaches out of the water: http://jsperf.com/loops/142

Using this approach the code would look like this:

```
function transform( node, f )
{
  node = f(node) || node;  
  if( node.length )
    for (var i = 0, child; child = node[i]; i++)
      node[i] = transform( child , f );
  return node;
}
```

Comment: Great implementations. They allow you see with one look what they do!

Comment: Sorry, but this is basically what I had before rewriting it. The reason I attempted to write a non-recursive algorithm is exactly because I was having massive slowdowns due to stack explosions. The interactive algorithm is self-restricted in space and thus the only real option if you really want speed. Also, commas are not evil. **They keep everything as an expression** and thus make the whole code much more friendlier for compilers targeting JavaScript, while being much cleaner and more powerful than the statement-based style.

Comment: @Dokkat But your code, it does not work per my first comment.

Comment: Also, I should have expressed myself better on the OP, so I'm sorry for that. It is meant for binary trees only, so obviously it breaks for other kinds of trees. Also, you provided a top-down transformer, which is not equivalent to a bottom-up transformer. Also, considering I expressed myself badly and you do provide an actually good answer for a similar problem, I'll be upvoting and accepting this answer in case nobody answers the actual problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Dokkat Thanks, I am curious, why must it be bottom-up?  Do you think it will be faster or are there other reasons ?

Comment: @konijn because working bottom-up is necessary to find redexes in a tree-reduction algorithm. That is, suppose you are reducing, `(+ (+ 1 2) 3)`. The first redex is obviously `(+ 1 2)` - the deeper. Reducing it results in `(+ 3 3)` which is another redex, which becomes `6`. Going top-down would not work, I guess.

Comment: @Last comment before CR bugs me to start a chat; it would be great if you could update your question or your fiddle with a more realistic data set.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I've decided to write something after all, however not about the performance, but about the coding style.

First off you should give more information what your function actually does. It took me a lot of time to understand that it you are working with binary trees here.

I don't like your use of the comma operator. All code conventions I know discourage its use like this.

Normally I'm fine with declaring all the variables at the start of the function instead of when they are used. However in this case, the declaration makes it look like all of the 
variables are used "globally" within the function, although most of them are just temporal use. This makes reading the code very difficult.

Additionally some of your variables (mainly `parent` and `dir`) seem to just duplicate the properties of the same name of the current `node`. This makes tracking the use of the variables and it's matching property very confusing IMHO.

Actually lets go through the variables one by one:

- **`root`**: With exception of setting the first `dir` property unused, and thus completely unnecessary.
- **`node`**: Should be called `currentNode`.
- **`child`**: One of the variables that seem to be "global", however is just used temporally in the `dir < 2` block. It should be declared there.
- **`parent`**: I admit I haven't quite undesrtood the point of this (and the corresponding `parent` property), but I'm quite sure you are just duplicating the value of `node.parent`. I think it should be possible to get rid of it all together.
- **`is_node`**: Like `child` just a temporary variable, so it's shouldn't be declared at the beginning of the function. Also it's named very badly. You are not using it when checking if a node "is a node", but if a node is an array (or has children, or if's not a leaf). So it should be called `is_array`, `has_children` or (if logically switched) `is_leaf`. However at the end, you don't need it at all IMHO. Instead just merge the two lines you are using it in.
- **`dir`**: Sorry, but it's the worst of them all:

  - Again just a temporary variable, that shouldn't be declared at the start of the function.
  - It also just duplicates the value of `node.dir`.
  - Very badly named. "dir" normally stands for "direction", which doesn't apply here. It's the "current index".
  - Worst of all: The use of the "magic" (and yet completely meaningless) number `2`.
  - Conclusion: Get rid of it. It's completely unnecessary.

Instead of:

```
is_node = typeof(node)==="object";
dir = is_node ? node.dir : 2;
if (dir < 2)
  child = node[dir],
```

use

```
if (typeof(node)==="object")
  child = node[node.dir],
```

---

There is much more, but I don't have the time right now. Maybe I'll come back.

Comment: Many of those were put on purpose and have a justification. Root is necessary to remember the first node, in order to stop computation. Parent and dir are duplicating boxed values because this provides huge performance boosts in JavaScript. About declaring temporary variables in the beginning of the function, this allows for the comma based style. The comma based style itself is much better because this way **everything is an expression**. This allows for much easier compiling back and fort of the code to other functional languages. The problem here is that "var" can't be used inside an (...)

Comment: expression, so the "var" declaration needs an statement. Including it on top of the function allows every function in the language to follow the same form: `function(<binds>){var <variables>; return <expression>}`. This is not the case because the function is particularly imperative and hand-optimized, but this keeps it in the same style of the rest of the code where compilers are used a lot. And yes, "dir" means directios: "0" = pointing left, "1" = pointing right, "2" = pointing up (or: go to parent). Magic numbers are necessary for performance reason plus lack of "ENUM" on JS.

Comment: The only thing I really agree is with the bad naming of "is_node". Indeed, "is_array" would be much better. The code itself is MUCH cleaner in the recursive version (it is a one liner!), but this is supposed to be fast version of it (recursion was up to 10x slower on my benchmarks because of stack explosion), so most of the things you complained about are necessary.

Comment: I assumed that these choices were made for perceived performance optimizations, however I don't believe they are actually justified (especially the comma operator), and I believe you should do some concrete performance tests for each "optimization", especially since IMHO they are probably strongly depended of the run-time engine.

Comment: But then lets talk about performance. First up: Why? JavaScript is rarely used in scenarios where such low level optimization is required. And to be honest, if you actually need such optimized performance (which you should prove BTW - and you still haven't said what you actually doing here), then you shouldn't be using JavaScript.

Comment: The actual application here is an structural editor for a functional language (Lambda Calculus enriched with numbers and lists) that runs on the browser. While a fast transformer is interesting for the interpreter/inliner/compiler/everything. The current slowdown happens when you are editing a deep AST (source code). My currently algorithm (recursive) is taking a long time (milliseconds) to apply some necessary transformations when you edit a node (eg: linking vars to their origin), due to stack explosion. That mini-lag is visible and worsens the user experience.

Comment: Another application of that editor is compiling the language and running it, so you can do interactive programming. So, sending the source to a server to compile it in a faster language and sending the result back would never be satisfactory, when the idea is that of "compile - see result".

Comment: About performance tests, I've done (not for this case) but in absolutely 100% of the algorithms, caching boxed variables provide huge performance boosts, sometimes even doubling it. So I've made that an automatic for performance intensive algorithms. Do the tests yourself if you want and you'll see what I'm talking about. And the comma is not about performance, but about keeping everything as an expression. This makes it much easier for compilers and parsers from FP-Languages <-> JavaScript. I also particularly believe it is much cleaner this way so I learned to love it.